# Facebook login exception: "Facebook auth is invalid for this user. error code 101"

Tags: android, facebook, parse-platform

I am using parse.com, and when logging in via Facebook it gives the following exception:

`Facebook auth is invalid for this user. error code 101`

Here is my AppClass code:

```
  public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Parse.initialize(new Parse.Configuration.Builder(this)
                .applicationId(Constant.APP_ID)
                .clientKey(Constant.CLIENT_KEY)
                .server(Constant.SERVER_URL)
                .enableLocalDataStore()
                .build()
        );

        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());

        ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);


    }
}
```

This is my LoginActivity:

```
 Collection<String> permissions = Arrays.asList("public_profile", "email");
    ParseFacebookUtils.logInWithReadPermissionsInBackground(LoginActivity.this, permissions, new LogInCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
            if (err != null) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();

                Log.e("err", "err"+ err.getLocalizedMessage()+" eror code "+err.getCode());
                if(!err.getLocalizedMessage().equalsIgnoreCase(""))
                showErrorToast(err.getLocalizedMessage(),false);
            }
            if (user == null) {
                ParseUser.logOut();
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "The user cancelled the Facebook login.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                Log.d("MyApp", "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
            } else if (user.isNew()) {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("MyApp", "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                getUserDetailFromFB();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this, "User logged in through Facebook.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d("MyApp", "User logged in through Facebook!");
                loginWithFb();
            }
        }
    });
```

How can I prevent this exception from occurring when logging in via Facebook?